# Estimate (on paper) the output of this function

Tags: summation, algorithms, estimation, recursive-algorithms

I am given a function:

```
define f(i,j):
    if i equals to 0 and j equals to 0:
        return 1
    else if i equals to 0 and j not equals to 0:
        return f(j-1,j-1)
    else:
        return f(i-1,j)+f(i-1,j-1)
```

and I am told to estimate f(14,14) quickly. I tried expanding everything out but did not see any pattern. The hint I was given was to imagine a grid with values at every lattice point, with (0,0) and (0,1) being 1. I don’t see how exactly this helps with the estimation, could someone guide me on this please? Thank you!

Comment: Is that function even well defined? I get $f(1,0)=f(0,0)+f(0,-1)$ which doesn't look good.

Comment: @Kusma - it turns out that you do not need to know $f(i,j)$ when $i \gt j$ to find $f(14,14)$, which is also $f(0,15)$ and the $15^\text{th}$ Bell number

Comment: Thank you @Henry, I should have tried to notice that...

Comment: Are you referring to j-factorial in the 4th line? Even 0! =1> 0.

Comment: @poetasis hi, that means not equals to! Using Python syntax here

Comment: Have edited it to pseudocode for easier readability!